# Type conversion error from LabeledPoint in pyspark.mllib, for using linear regression model in pyspark.ml

Tags: pyspark, linear-regression

I have the following code for linear regression using pyspark.ml package. However I get this error message for the last line, when the model is being fit:

> IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column features must
>   be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was
>   actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce.

Does anyone has an idea what is missing? 
Is there any replacement in `pyspark.ml` for `LabeledPoint` in `pyspark.mllib`?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
import numpy as np
from pandas import *


data = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/w7baik1x1487076820914/randomTableSmall.csv")

def parsePoint(line):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]
    return LabeledPoint(values[1], [values[0]])


points_df = data.map(parsePoint).toDF()

lr = LinearRegression()

model = lr.fit(points_df, {lr.regParam:0.0})
```

Comment: Please can you let me know the spark version you are using and a sample of the file that you are trying to import

Comment: pyspark.ml uses dataframes api whereas you don't have any column names such as 'label' and 'features', is there some part of the code that you have not posted.

Comment: This is the entire code causing the error.
and here are few first lines from the data file, which is being read with the function `parsePoint`:

0.656992798279138,2.5834056958606

0.716673783763451,2.36159163031627

0.259623437084048,1.69482312701634

Comment: I am using spark version 2.0.
@GauravDhama

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that newer versions of spark have a Vector class in linalg module of ml and you do not need to get it from mllib.linalg. Also the newer versions do not accept spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT in ml. here is the code that would work for you :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
import numpy as np


data = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/w7baik1x1487076820914/randomTableSmall.csv")

def parsePoint(line):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]
    return (values[1], Vectors.dense([values[0]]))


points_df = data.map(parsePoint).toDF(['label','features'])

lr = LinearRegression()

model = lr.fit(points_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark newer versions don't accept spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT (you do not need to get it from mllib.linalg).

try to replace

`from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint`

by:

`from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors`